# Removing Item from List

Tags: vb.net, list

My code is supposed to remove item from list but its not removing item.

My Code:

```
dim myRoom as Room = New Room()
Dim myRoomList as List( of Room ) = new List( of Room )

...
myRoomList.add(myRoom)
msgbox(myRoomList.count)

...
myRoomList.remove(myRoom)
msgbox(myRoomList.count)
```

Comment: By all accounts this should remove the item. We'll need more info. How do you know it's not removing? What is the code that you have snipped out?

Comment: i am using count method to check... after removing item also its returning the same old counted value

Comment: The code you've shown undoubtedly works perfectly. The problem must lie in the sections you've snipped out with `...`

Comment: From watch panel before and after the myRoomList.remove(myRoom) the count shows same value

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that there is no item being added before the removal, so that the count is not increased again. Try using this for a test...

```
dim myRoom as Room = New Room()
Dim myRoomList as List( of Room ) = new List( of Room )

...
myRoomList.add(myRoom)
msgbox(myRoomList.count)

...
msgbox(myRoomList.count)
myRoomList.remove(myRoom)
msgbox(myRoomList.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason for this not to remove the item is when you have overriden the `Equals` method of the `Room` class with errors. For example, the following code would exhibit such a behaviour:

```
Class Room
    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

If that’s not the case, then the error is elsewhere and the code you have shown us does in fact work.